Как получить список чатов телеграм(tdlib)?
Есть проблема получением списка чатов телеграмма, в документации указано, что для получаения списка чатов используется метод LoadChats, который принимает 2 аргумента,ChatList, и лимит(целое число), а что делать дальше со всем этим не понятно.
                TdApi.ChatListMain listChat = new ChatListMain();
                _client.Send(new TdApi.LoadChats(listChat, 100), _defaultHandler);
                private class DefaultHandler : Td.ClientResultHandler
                {
                    void Td.ClientResultHandler.OnResult(TdApi.BaseObject @object)
                    {
                       Print(@object.ToString());
                    }
                }


Из документации TDLib:

Loads more chats from a chat list. The loaded chats and their positions in the chat list will be sent through updates. Chats are sorted by the pair (chat.position.order, chat.id) in descending order. Returns a 404 error if all chats have been loaded.

Вы должны обрабатывать каждый новый чат через обновление TdApi.UpdateNewChat (или что-то подобное, я пишу не на C#).
